# How to get all registered TouchIDs in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, touch-id

Can any one guide me to retrieve all the registered TouchIDs from device ?

I am using LocalAuthentication framework for TouchID authentication. My requirement is to get the latest registered TouchID. Please help me if anyone know it.

Comment: You mean access the individual fingerprints? The image data, name, or what? I don't think the SDK provides that functionality. It only tells you if the user authenticated successfully or not.

Comment: Everything you can achieve with TouchID is in the docs for LocalAuthentication and Keychain (Security.framework).

Comment: Ya i need to get the information like how many fingerprints are available, name kind of things

Comment: i have gone through Security and LocalAuthentication frameworks but didn't find anything related to my requirement

Comment: That's because you can't get the information you want. It is none of your (app's) business

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. So there is no way to get each fingerprint information right?

Comment: Correct. It is sensitive information and secured